# EXCEPTION FOR BLOCK 202612 , from what's it bassed and where it was fixed?

Tags: blockchain, development, altcoin

who can  asnwer me this for litle qustion , i find  this at code

```
// EXCEPTION FOR BLOCK 202612     
const std::string correct_blob_hash_202612 = "3a8a2b3a29b50fc86ff73dd087ea43c6f0d6b8f936c849194d5c84c737903966";     
const std::string existing_block_id_202612 = "bbd604d2ba11ba27935e006ed39c9bfdd99b76bf4a50654bc1e1e61217962698";`
```

how was it calculated ' if it's new chain , this option need ? or this option only for fix some bug before hardfork ? and not need if used 6 ver hard fork ?

i want  udernstand what make this exception

Answer (score 2):

There was a bug in the `tree_hash` function used to compute the transaction Merkle tree that caused the hash of block 202612 to be `bbd604d2ba11ba27935e006ed39c9bfdd99b76bf4a50654bc1e1e61217962698` instead of the correct value `3a8a2b3a29b50fc86ff73dd087ea43c6f0d6b8f936c849194d5c84c737903966`.

There is a comment in the file *src/crypto/tree-hash.c* about this:

```
// The blockchain block at height 202612 http://monerochain.info/block/bbd604d2ba11ba27935e006ed39c9bfdd99b76bf4a50654bc1e1e61217962698
// contained 514 transactions, that triggered bad calculation of variable "cnt" in the original version of this function
// as from CryptoNote code.
//
// This bug applies to all CN altcoins.
//
// Mathematical bug here was first published on 14:45:34 (GMT+2) 2014-09-04 by Rafal Freeman <rfree>
// https://github.com/rfree2monero/bitmonero/commit/b417abfb7a297d09f1bbb6de29030f8de9952ac8
// and soon also applied to CryptoNote (15:10 GMT+2), and BoolBerry used not fully correct work around:
// the work around of sizeof(size_t)*8 or <<3 as used before in 2 coins and in BBL later was blocking
// exploitation on normal platforms, how ever we strongly recommend the following fix because it removes
// mistake in mathematical formula.
```

As block 202612 has been accepted in the blockchain with the bad hash, this bad hash is now hard coded as the "official" one instead of the mathematically correct hash.